# Search List in Xaml with C# using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, xaml, search, windows-store-apps

I am using a MVC Web Api, in which I can get a list of items in my windows store app client.

I can view the list of items on the windows store app using this code:

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:12345/api/items");

var sampleDataGroups = new List<SampleDataGroup>();


            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                // CL: Parse 1 Item from the content
               var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);
                //IEnumerable<string> item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<string>>(content);

                foreach (var data in item)
                {
                      var dataGroup = new SampleDataGroup
                            (

                                (string)data.Id.ToString(),
                                (string)data.Name,
                                (string)"",
                                (string)data.PhotoUrl,
                                (string)data.Description

                            );
                                 sampleDataGroups.Add(dataGroup);
                }
             }
            else
            {
                MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("Error");
                await dlg.ShowAsync();
            }


            this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = sampleDataGroups;
```

The data is received in this json format, that is, data for each item in the list

```
data    {
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "bat",
  "Description": "lorem ipsum",
  "Price": 1.39,
  "Weight": "75g",
  "Photo": "test.png",
  "ItemList": null
}

dynamic {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject}
```

This maps to the SampleDataGroups structure in the touch app:

```
public class SampleDataGroup : SampleDataCommon
    {
        public SampleDataGroup()
        {

        }

        public SampleDataGroup(String uniqueId, String title, String subtitle, String imagePath, String description)
            : base(uniqueId, title, subtitle, imagePath, description)
        {
            Items.CollectionChanged += ItemsCollectionChanged;
        }
}
```

I want to create a search items feature on my windows app, for this I created a search facility in xaml by adding a textbox and button control.

```
<TextBox x:Name="SearchTB" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Search our Products"   Grid.Column="1"Width="420" Height="50" />

<Button x:Name="Product_Search" Content="Go" Grid.Column="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" Height="50" Margin="0 0 0 0" Click="Product_Search_Click" />
```

I want to use a linq query to get and return all the items that match the string entered in the textbox when the button is clicked.

I created this function below for when the button is clicked. The `string query` parameter is meant to be the string entered in the textbox. Any items that are similar to the string entered in the textbox, should be returned.

```
private void Item_Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       var querystr = SearchTB.Text; 

}
```

How do I get the list of items to display on click of the button using the string entered in the search textbox, using Linq?

Comment: What is the format of data you receive inside HttpResponseMessage? Do you map it to some data structure or just use the raw data?

Comment: Please see the edited code above. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do something like:

```
private void Item_Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var groups =  DefaultViewModel["Groups"] as IEnumerable<SampleDataGroup>;
    if (groups == null) 
        return;

    DefaultViewModel["FilteredGroups"] =
       groups 
            .Where(group => ContainsQueryString(group. Title, Search.Text))
            .ToList();
}

private static bool ContainsQueryString(string property, string query)
{
    //performs comparison based on the current UI culture, case insensitive
    //from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring
    return CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(property, query, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: But does this take the string query from the Textbox `x:Name="SearchTB"`?

Comment: So your main problem is in getting the string from the text box?

Comment: See the change above to the click function. I want to use the string entered in the textbox, to find all the groups in the list whose `Name` is matched or similar to the string enetered

Comment: See the updated answer. If I understand right, it's very easy, the thing you want.

Comment: I get an error: `Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
`

Comment: This is because the list is being saved in the DefaultViewModel in an untyped manner. See the correction I made.

Comment: I actually sorted most of it out. I have problem with the linq query however. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627465/filter-list-with-linq-for-similar-items

Comment: You should do the comparison using the *CompareInfo* if you want to support languages other than English.