# Filter list with linq for similar items

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2012

I have a list in which I filter, according to the text input in a TextBox in Xaml. The code below filters the List stored in the `results` variable. The code checks if the textbox input,ie, `queryString`, matches the `Name` of any item in the `results` list EXACTLY. This only brings back the items from the list where the string matches the Name of a the item exactly.

```
var filteredItems = results.Where(
                p => string.Equals(p.Name, queryString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

How do I change this so that it returns the items in the list whose `Name`, is **similar** to the queryString?

To describe what I mean by **Similar**:
An item in the list has a Name= Smirnoff Vodka. I want it so that if "vodka" or  "smirnoff" is entered in the textbox, the the item Smirnoff Vodka will be returned.

As it is with the code above, to get Smirnoff Vodka returned as a result, the exact Name "Smirnoff Vodka" would have to be entered in the textbox.

Comment: Visual Studio is an editor and does not provide any indication of what version of .Net you are using. Providing a .Net version would be better.

Comment: It all depends what you mean by similar :)

Comment: VS 2012, using C# and is for a Windows Store App, I'm not sure why but the Target Framework section in the project properties is greyed out.

Comment: @NedStoyanov You can see the edited question for a description on what I mean by similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you mean, by saying "similar"

**Options:**

```
1) var filteredItems = results.Where( p => p.Name != null && p.Name.ToUpper().Contains(queryString.ToUpper());
```

2) There is also also known algorithm as "Levenshtein distance":

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13525/Fast-memory-efficient-Levenshtein-algorithm

The last link contains the source code in c#. By using it you cann determine "how close" the query string to the string in your list.

Comment: You can see the edited question for a description on what I mean by similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fileList.Where(item => filterList.Contains(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var query = "Smirnoff Vodka";
var queryList = query.Split(new [] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var fileList = new List<string>{"smirnoff soup", "absolut vodka", "beer"};

var result = from file in fileList
             from item in queryList
             where file.ToLower().Contains(item.ToLower())
             select file;
```